# Best way to get the xml string only

Tags: java, xml

What is the best way to get the xml string from a string contains weird characters before the xml part? I have a string contains some invalid characters with xml string like below. I'd like to extract only xml from the string removing all the weird character before the xml part.
Thanks in advance.

```
%--:00abcd102312 01203918 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

Comment: Can the text before the XML contain a `<` character?

Comment: No.. its not but I'd like to avoid iterating each character until first < character appears. Should it be more efficient if I use regular expression?

Comment: What do you think regex will do? (Only the code will be nicer.)

Comment: thats true.. its good to have code looks nice :D

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the xml bit with regular expressions, a basic one like this works for given example:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(<\\?.*)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(" your string here ");

if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

Comment: should it look like Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(<\\?.*)")? (two back slash)